# How do I join another table to this Query

Tags: mysql, join

This is the first time am seeing such a complex query. Below is the Query and I need to join another table called "**profiles**" on **profile_id**.

**Table Structure**

[image]

**Original Query**

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM messages a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT message_replay_id, MAX(message_id) AS latest_message
        FROM messages
        WHERE message_from = '1' || message_to = '1'
        GROUP BY message_replay_id 
    ) b
    ON a.message_replay_id = b.message_replay_id
    AND a.message_id = b.latest_message
    ORDER BY a.message_id DESC
```

So, It will be JOINING ON **message_to = profile_id**.

**This is what I' am currently trying out**

```
SELECT a.* FROM messages a
    INNER JOIN(SELECT message_replay_id, MAX(message_id) AS latest_message FROM messages WHERE message_from = '1' || message_to = '1' GROUP BY message_replay_id ) b
    ON a.message_replay_id = b.message_replay_id AND a.message_id = b.latest_message
    INNER JOIN(SELECT * AS latest_profile FROM PROFILES WHERE profile_id = b.latest_message ) c
    ON a.message_replay_id = b.message_replay_id AND a.message_id = b.latest_message
ORDER BY a.message_id DESC
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS latest_profile FROM profiles WHERE profile_id = b.latest_message ) c
    ON a.m' at line 4
```

**Help me guys, how will I join another table.**

Comment: Provide proper DDLs for your table definitions

Comment: Extending @MKhalidJunaid's point... consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: `SELECT * AS latest_profile` makes no sense`. `AS` is used for giving an alias to a table or a single column in the `SELECT` list. You can't given alias to `*`. Also, your second `ON` clause should reference something in the `c` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a table alias inside a subquery in the `from` clause.  Instead:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m INNER JOIN
     (SELECT message_replay_id, MAX(message_id) AS latest_message
      FROM messages
      WHERE message_from = '1' || message_to = '1'
      GROUP BY message_replay_id
     ) mm
     ON m.message_replay_id = mm.message_replay_id AND
        m.message_id = mm.latest_message INNER JOIN
     profiles p 
     ON p.profile_id = mm.latest_message
ORDER BY mm.message_id DESC;
```

In addition:

- `as` in inappropriate with `*` (in general).  It can only rename one column.
- You don't need to repeat the `join` conditions between the first two tables.
- The subquery for `profiles` is unnecessary and hurts performance in MySQL.
- Queries are easier to follow if the table aliases are table abbreviations.